# Validating java timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, regex, numbers

I have a php-based API, which accepts uploads from Android devices (read - Java).  The data comes in JSON format and one of the fields is java timestamp, e.g. `1421100231554`.  The PHP code is checking (rather simplistically) for the validity of this timestamp using this (simplified) code:

```
function check_num($num, $len) {
    return preg_match("/^\\d{$len}$/", $num);
}

if(!check_num($data['timestamp'], 13)) {
    exit_error('Invalid timestamp');
}
```

This `check_num` function is called from many different places.

Later this timestamp was used to insert data into a database using this code (this part is hardly relevant for the purpose of this question).

```
$dt = new DateTime();                                                                                             
$dt->setTimestamp($data['timestamp'] / 1000);
...
$stmt->execite(array(...
                     ':tmstmp' => $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
```

This worked well for my purposes - up until we migrated the hosting from Fedora 4 (don't ask) to the latest CentOS.  Now this code stopped working, because `preg_match('/^\d+$/', $data['timestamp'])` is returning `0`.  I started digging into it - and turned out that PHP is converting the 13-digit number into its scientific notation, i.e. `1.42110023155E+12`.  This obviously throws off the pattern matcher.

The timestamp comes in as a number, not a string, that is, the relevant piece of JSON is:

```
[
  {
     "timestamp":1421100231554,
     "customer":100274,
     "type":"warehouse",
     "items":[...]
  }
]
```

I don't have any control over the Android app that sends the data, so any tweaks I have to make, have to be on the server side in PHP.

How can I fix the PHP code to work correctly again?

Comment: `if (is_int($data['timestamp']))` should do it.

Comment: @amphetamachine It's not the same - it doesn't check for 13 digits. As I stated, I have calls to this function from many places where I specify the expected length of the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two schools of thought on this:

If you invoke [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with the `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` flag set in the options, it should pass any integer too big to represent as an int back as a string. This should keep the precision:

```
$myJson = '{"time":71055011577700000000}'; // too big to fit into 64-bit int
$myobj = json_decode($myJson,false,512,JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
var_dump($myObj);

object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["time"]=>
  string(20) "71055011577700000000"
}
```

The other school of thought is you shouldn't be using regex on numeric values to determine if they're in the specified range. Use math... on numbers. Revolutionary, I know:

```
if ($data['timestamp'] > 1e14) {
    die('more than 13 digits in your int!');
} elseif ($data['timestamp'] < 1) {
    die('your int is too small');
}
```

Comment: The flag to `json_decode` did it.  As for using math to check numbers, yes, that would be the correct way, however I'm working with somebody else's code and I don't want to start fixing things that otherwise work; I have enough problems as it is, considering that we are migrating from php 5.1 to php 5.4 - the old server hasn't been updated in years.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, your last comment... :)

Then try

```
$i = gmp_init( $number );
$timestamp = gmp_strval( $i );
```

Comment: he dont have ctrl over it

Comment: `json_decode($jsonstring,false,512,JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING)` will do that too.

Comment: I get the error `PHP Warning:  gmp_strval(): Unable to convert variable to GMP - wrong type in - on line 1`

Comment: @amphetamachine This did the trick!  Add it as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: i updated my code, but amphetamachines solutions seems good too